# Blu-rays don't work on vlc

Tags: vlc, blu-ray

I have a Panasonic UJ-120 BD-ROM Drive and I also have KEYDB.cfg in `~/.config/aacs`. However when I try to play the bluray in vlc it says 
`Bluray Error: AACS: MMC Failed`. What do I do?